# How to install a Bitcoin client on Ubuntu Server

Tags: json-rpc, ubuntu, server

I've googled a lot for this issue. Hehe. I have found some tutorials, but they were of no use because they are for systems that do have a GUI. I have no plans to install a GUI on that system, and I want to use bitcoin from the command line, or via RPC API. This is the system I run:

> Linux redacted 3.2.0-40-generic-pae #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 21:44:41 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

I found I can do this:

> sudo apt-get install bitcoind

But hardly I know what to do with it after that. It installs successfully. If you are going to ask a reason why I want this, it's because I want to communicate with it via PHP or I'll see how, but mostly it's for automating services with it. Please help. :-(

Comment: When installed, can I use the client for getting payed on apache (php or tomcat) web pages?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've installed bitcoind, you should create a [configuration file](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) (stored in `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`) containing at least an RPC username and password, and then you just run `bitcoind` to start the server.

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking right now how can I add it to system startup.

Answer (score 6):

`Edited answer after Tom van der Woerdt's comment about using an untrusted repo`

from: https://gist.github.com/WyseNynja/2503687

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git-core build-essential libssl-dev libboost-all-dev libdb5.1-dev libdb5.1++-dev libgtk2.0-dev

git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin/src

make -f makefile.unix clean; make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP= bitcoind

# from #bitcoin-dev:
# sacarlson: USE_UPNP= : don't build upnp, USE_UPNP=0 : build but disable by default, USE_UPNP=1 : build but enable by default

# optionally, 
strip bitcoind
```

download blockchain (check against http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount):

```
bitcoind
```

test bitcoind:

```
bitcoind getbalance
bitcoind getaccountaddress account #(where account is the rpcuser account you created earlier in your bitcoind.conf file.) It will look like this: 1djfdLXSgqrwtexqkn9JewSrCJU4vu74eR4
```

send coins to the address and doublecheck `bitcoind getbalance`

Comment: Baaaad idea. Untrusted repo, while the default ones have it too.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Can anyone else confirm this, because the INSTALL file tells you to install using `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`

Comment: After cloning a repo, for reliable operation, you should `git checkout` the current stable release version.

Answer (score 0):

I already posted this answer, but it's gone for some reason. If some moderator deleted it, then I am ok with it, but shame on them for not informing me. In any case, here is the shell script I run on my computers to get bitcoin up and running:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Word of caution, I am not an experienced shell programmer. All I can #
# guarantee is that this script has worked for me, and that it has     #
# done so on multiple Ubuntu machines (one 11.10 and one 13.10), so    #
# hopefully it will work for you too                                   #

# Install some packages as instructed on various web sites
sudo apt-get -y install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libtool autotools-dev autoconf
sudo apt-get -y install libdb4.8-dev     # Generally this step fails
sudo apt-get -y install libdb4.8++-dev   # Generally this step fails
sudo apt-get -y install libboost1.37-dev # Sometimes this step fail
sudo apt-get -y install libboost-all-dev # Sometimes this step fail
sudo apt-get -y install libminiupnpc-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libdb++-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libprotobuf-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libqrencode-dev


# Build berkley db4.8
# Technically, this should only be installed if the above              #
# libdb4.8XX-dev packages failed to install but nothing beats a little #
# overkill =)                                                          #
cd ~/Downloads

if [ ! -e db-4.8.30 ]
then
   wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.tar.gz
   tar zxvf db-4.8.30.tar.gz
   rm -f db-4.8.30.tar.gz
fi

cd db-4.8.30/build_unix
../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx # If this doesn't work, try removing or changing prefix
make
sudo make install
cd ~/Downloads
rm -fr db-4.8.30/

# Build bitcoin
cd ~/Downloads
if [ ! -e bitcoin ]
then
   git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin ~/Downloads/bitcoin
fi

cd bitcoin

./autogen.sh
./configure # Non Ubuntu 13.xx versions
# ./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu # Ubuntu 13.xx version
make
sudo make install

cd ~/Downloads
rm -fr bitcoin
```

Comment: If any of your posts were deleted you can see them by checking your profile. At the bottom of answers/questions overview is a link "show recently deleted answers/questions". I think you might also get a "response flag" (not sure). If you wish to inquire what happened to your answer, please see [How can I know why my post was deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130725/how-can-i-know-why-my-post-was-deleted), and if that doesn't resolve it for you, please post a question in [meta].

Answer (score 0):

In the Open Synaptic Package manager, search: bitcoin and click install.
Bitcoin is already in the UBUNTU repositories.

Answer (score 0):

This is ubuntu we're talking about.

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to get them but i am getting the api of functionalities which are in the link https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin bit not related to client api list which are in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: Welcome to BitcoinSE! Your answer can be improved if you state what "them" are and possibly explain how you use the api.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, once you run it after install, It could take up to 7 hours to update your wallet. After it's updated. Remember to encrypt your bitcoin wallet with a hard password but one you can never forget. Because if you do forget your password, All your bitcoins will be lost.

Comment: Please edit your answers to improve them or comment on them instead of adding additional answers.